# Where are the values of this variable coming from? Doesn't seemed to be defined anywhere

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I am new to Rstudio and I'm trying to learn how to use R Markdown. When I create a new R Markdown file, I am greeted with the following default document.

[image]

Note how I've specifically assigned the 'cars' variable a NULL value, yet when running it cars becomes a data frame populated with values. Given that there is no assignment anywhere within the document or any variables present in the environment, it really bothers me not know the source for those values.

I would greatly appreciate knowing how the cars dataframes comes to be from apparently spontaneously.

Comment: `cars` is a sample dataset included with `R`. See `?cars` for more info.

Comment: @Ben: since that solves the issue, you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

A basic fact about knitting markdown documents is that all the evaluations occur in an environment specific only to that doc.

Since your assignment of `NULL` to `cars` does not occur in the Rmd doc, then it is in a separate environment to the Rmd doc and has no relevance to the output of the Rmd when it's knitted. Instead, in the output of your knitted Rmd doc you see the built-in dataset that @SeñorO mentioned.